# column ambiguously defined, but why? (ORA-00918)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating an application that runs SQL queries for us. I've copied this query from a script that is working, but when I paste it in SQL developer or vs code it gives me a ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined error. I can't find where the issue lies. Hopefully someone can see it and explain what is going wrong.

```
    select to_char(STARTTIMESTAMP, 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss DY') as "DATE",
       bridgeid,
       requestType,
       RequestSpecification,
       bfa.faultdescription,
       case
         when requestMessage is not null then
          dbms_lob.substr(substr(bMes.requestMessage,
                                 INSTR(bMes.requestMessage, 'SourceSystem', 1) +
                                 length('SourceSystem') + 1,
                                 (INSTR(bMes.requestMessage,
                                        'SourceSystem',
                                        1,
                                        2) - INSTR(bMes.requestMessage,
                                                    'SourceSystem',
                                                    1) -
                                 length('SourceSystem') - 3)))
       end as sourceSystem,
       case
         when requestMessage is not null then
          dbms_lob.substr(substr(bMes.requestMessage,
                                 INSTR(bMes.requestMessage, 'EventId', 1) +
                                 length('EventId') + 1,
                                 (INSTR(bMes.requestMessage, 'EventId', 1, 2) -
                                 INSTR(bMes.requestMessage, 'EventId', 1) -
                                 length('EventId') - 3)))
       end as EventId,
       bint.MessageId,
       bint.relatesto,
       systimestamp
  from baseintegrationheaders bint
  left join baseMessages bMes
    on bMes.relatesto = bint.relatesto
  left join basefaults bfa
    on bfa.relatesto = bint.relatesto
where 1 = 1
   and STARTTIMESTAMP Between
       (trunc(systimestamp, 'hh') +
       floor(to_char(systimestamp, 'mi') / 15) * 15 / 1440) - 15 / 1440 And
       trunc(systimestamp, 'hh') +
       floor(to_char(systimestamp, 'mi') / 15) * 15 / 1440
   and bint.technicaldomain = 'WB'
   and bint.bridgeid in ('AST_GPSBatch_Reply-bridge',
                          'AST_GPSOnline_Reply-bridge',
                          'AST_GPS_Request-bridge')
   and requestType not in ( 'WorkerRunning'
                          , 'BridgeEnd'
                          , 'BridgeStart'
                          , 'WorkerEnd'
                          , 'WorkerMQEnd'
                          , 'WorkerMQStart'
                          , 'WorkerProducerEnd'
                          , 'WorkerProducerStart'
                          , 'WorkerReaderEnd'
                          , 'WorkerReaderStart'
                          , 'WorkerStart'
                          , 'WorkerStop'
                          )
   and ((requestType = 'BridgeRequest' and faultindication = 'true') or
       (requestType <> 'BridgeRequest'))
order by bint.MessageId, 1
;
```

Comment: Try using alias with all columns.

Comment: We don_'t know your tables, so we can not guess which of the columns have the same name

Comment: You aren't using aliases for all the columns you select. One or more of the columns you are selecting are present in multiple tables. E.g. `STARTTIMESTAMP` or `requestType`.

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns, at least when several tables are involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do:

```sql
SELECT column_name
FROM   table_a a
       INNER JOIN table_b b
       ON (a.something = b.something)
```

and both `table_a` and `table_b` contain the column `column_name` then you will get the error `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`.

The solution is to prefix the ambiguous identifier with the appropriate table alias (or, if you are not using aliases, table name):

```sql
SELECT b.column_name
FROM   table_a a
       INNER JOIN table_b b
       ON (a.something = b.something)
```

Since you do not tell use which columns are in which tables we cannot give you a specific answer for your query; but you can apply the above technique and prefix any ambiguously named columns with the appropriate table aliases. (Or better, prefix all identifiers with the appropriate aliases.)

The identifiers you (may) need to fix include: `starttimestamp`, `bridgeid`, `requestType`, `RequestSpecification`, `requestMessage` and `faultindication`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and explanation. I've marked it as an answer. I had one side question; do you perhaps know why this would work for a script that has been running for months, but not on my local machine? I literally just copy and pasted this. That's why I'm confused

Comment: @Beerus239 I would check if the tables have different columns between your local machine and the other machine. If your copy of `table_a` has an `xyz` column and the `table_a` on the other machine does not then you will get different behaviour.

Comment: makes sense! Thank you again and all the best!

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined error`
means in your sql, you join two tables which both have the same column, but you don't figure out which one to `select`

Comment: In this case, you can add table before each column

Answer (score 0):

The ORA-00918 error in Oracle typically occurs when there's an ambiguity in column names in your SQL query. It means that a column referenced in the query exists in multiple tables, and Oracle doesn't know which one to use. To resolve this issue, you need to specify the table or alias for each column in your query to remove the ambiguity.

Basically, provide alias name for all columns used in the query that will make sure you are getting it from the correct table.